Why do you need to set aside 10 cards when setting up the game?
The rules of Saboteur 2 state you should set aside 10 cards from the main deck when you set up the game, then at the end of the game you put them back in the deck but set aside 10 cards again for the next round.
What is the purpose of these 10 cards set aside? And also, is it the same 10 being set aside each time, or are the previous ones reshuffled back into the deck and new 10 set aside?

This is a setup mechanic used in several games, for mostly the same reason as described in the answer below: it makes card counting unreliable. I can think of No Thanks (where you want to connect straights, and you sit there with 9 and 11, but 10 might never show up) and Love Letter (where knowing exactly what cards your opponents have on the final play of the game would be overpowered) off the top of my head.

It's to create variety and uncertainty between games. It's a different, random set of ten cards put aside each time — after you shuffle the deck, take ten cards off the top or bottom, put them aside, and don't look at them.
Saboteur 1 and 2 both play out until every single card in the deck is drawn and played, or until the miners find the treasure. This means if you played without setting any cards aside you'd be guaranteed to see a certain number of rockslides, broken tools, and so on. But you'd also be guaranteed a certain number of ladders, and a certain number of fix tools, so you can usually depend on being able to counter every act of sabotage the same way every time. It's just a matter of when those get drawn and which team draws them. Those guarantees would create a very uniform experience because there's a lot you can simply depend on being inevitable, and you'd have to play your cards mindful of what is guaranteed to be played eventually.
Removing ten cards from the deck removes the guarantee and makes the game uncertain: you can no longer be sure which cards you'll see in this game or how many. If someone hasn't played a rockslide or a break tools yet, you don't know whether it's been drawn and being held for the right moment, or whether there won't even be one this game. If someone breaks your tools, there's no guarantee you'll be able to repair them ever. If someone caves in your tunnel, you can't play assuming you'll see a ladder later. And it goes without saying you can't depend on finding even one map.
That uncertainty creates a tense and unpredictable game and creates variability between any two play sessions. It's for the same reason that the game varies how many saboteurs there will be, so you're not guaranteed you've found the correct number of them.
